# knitr: automate producing multiple versions of PDF for beamer slides

Tags: r, latex, knitr, beamer

For lectures, I am using `knitr` to produce LaTeX `beamer` slides as a PDF.  For a given lecture, I want to produce also (a) 1-up handout (using the `handout` option, and (b) the same handout formatted 4-up.

I find I have to run knitr 3 times to do this as shown below.  Is there a way to simplify this work flow?

A lecture stub:

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{beamer} 

\input{inputs/beamer-setup}
\input{inputs/defs}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
 ...
\end{document}
```

And I run `knitr` as

```
knit2pdf("Lecture1.Rnw")
```

To get the 1-up handout (which suppresses the separate pages when you use transitions), I edit the first line to:

```
\documentclass[10pt,table,handout]{beamer}
```

and run

```
knit2pdf("Lecture1.Rnw" output="Lecture1-1up.tex")
```

Finally, to get the 2 x 2 version, I use the LaTeX `pgfpages` package,

```
\documentclass[10pt,table,handout]{beamer} 

\input{inputs/beamer-setup}
\input{inputs/defs}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[letterpaper,landscape]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
```

And run:

```
knit2pdf("Lecture1.Rnw" output="Lecture1-4up.tex")
```

(I found that with beamer, I could not simply print the PDF 4-up using Adobe Acrobat -- it generated a corrupt PDF file.  I was forced to use `pgfpages`)

Then, of course I have to revert my `.Rnw` file to the original if I need  re-do the slides. Very tedious.  There must be a better way.

Comment: I don't know if there's a `knitr` way to do this, but if not, why not write an R function to do it?  The function would write 3 little files that had the variable parts and `\input{mainpart}` to get the rest, then run `knit2pdf` on each of those little files.  You just edit the main part, then run the function to produce the 3 versions.